# What is the difference between NSLayoutAttributeBaseline and NSLayoutAttributeBottom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, constraints

The Apple docs usefully state that `NSLayoutAttributeBaseline` aligns to "The object’s baseline". What's a baseline? How is that different from the bottom?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Baseline applies to views such as `UILabel`. The baseline would be the position where the bottom of uppercase letters appear. For most other views (if not all others) the baseline and the bottom are the same.

Answer (score 14):

`NSLayoutAttributeBaseline` 
[image]

`NSLayoutAttributeBottom`
[image]