# Need an explanation of NSLayoutAttributeBaseline

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

Can anybody please provide a simple explanation of `NSLayoutAttributeBaseline`, `NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline` and `NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline`? Why do we need it? What is a good example of using it? Apple's explanation of this topic doesn't seem to be clear and obvious. Can't find good examples throughout the web as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, what is it called. The baseline of the text of a view.

Imagine you have view with text inside, let's say a label. And you have another view with that, but it has a box around it (so it is taller). Aligning the top edge or the bottom edge would have the text on different heights. With this attribute, you can align the text in two views of different kinds.

Here is an example with top, bottom and baseline alignment

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Baseline applies to views such as UILabel. The baseline would be the position where the bottom of uppercase letters appears. For most other views (if not all others) the baseline and the bottom are the same.

For more you can follow the thread: [What is the difference between NSLayoutAttributeBaseline and NSLayoutAttributeBottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883439/what-is-the-difference-between-nslayoutattributebaseline-and-nslayoutattributebo)